# Is there a way to use a variable in a function with f-string in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have 2 variables *n1* and *n2*. When I press space *randNum* is either equal to 1 or 2 and if it is equal to 1 then I want to change *n1* and if it is equal to 2 then I want to change *n2*. I am using **.itemconfig()** to change the variable but I do not know how to asign it to the variable that I want to change. I tried to somehow do it with f-string but that does not work. Is there any way to do it? Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack()


n1 = canvas.create_text(100, 100, font="Arial 25", text="1")
n2 = canvas.create_text(100, 150, font="Arial 25", text="2")


def function(event):
    if event.keysym == 'space':
        randNum = random.randint(1,2)
        canvas.itemconfig(f"n{randNum}", font="Arial 25", fill="red", text=randNum) #does not work


canvas.bind_all('<Key>', function)


tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can simply use ```if randNum==1```, ```n1...```,```else```,```n2...```

Comment: You can put a ternary condition like `canvas.itemconfig(n1 if randNum==1 else n2, font="Arial 25", fill="red", text=randNum)`

Comment: Yes this works but what do I do if there is more variables? I mean like n3, n4,..., n50, n51,... I think that having that many if's would not be very effective.

Comment: @AkOs49 then just place more if statements after else: `n1 if cond == 1 else n2 if cond == 2 else n3 if cond == 3 else n4` however at the end probably put None so that You can eval all the conditions if needed because otherwise in the above example anything that is not 1, 2 or 3 will make n4 be the variable

Comment: @AkOs49 I just read what You actually asked, well for having a lot of variables I would suggest a dictionary, then accessing the value on condition would be simple for example You could just have the key as condition say `{1: 'value'}` then instead of if just place `dct[cond]` where `dct` is the dictionary where all those values and keys are stored and `cond` is the condition to check so basically in this case it would be say 1 so if the user or sth inputed 1 the value from that key in the dictionary will be shown or sth, in this case tho have to account for key not being in the dictionary

Comment: My example conforms to your question of using formatted string to change text colors.

Comment: Your use of `f"n{randNum}"` will not work as it creates a string when `itemconfig` requires a reference to a `text` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tags` option of `create_text()`:

```
n1 = canvas.create_text(100, 100, font="Arial 25", text="1", tags="n1")
n2 = canvas.create_text(100, 150, font="Arial 25", text="2", tags="n2")


def function(event):
    if event.keysym == 'space':
        randNum = random.randint(1,2)
        canvas.itemconfig(f"n{randNum}", font="Arial 25", fill="red", text=randNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish the text colors to oscillate between black and red then here is one option.

```py
n0 = canvas.create_text(100, 100, font="Arial 25", text="1")
n1 = canvas.create_text(100, 150, font="Arial 25", text="2")

def function(event):
    r  = random.randrange(2)
    c = [ "red", "black" ]
    if r: c.reverse()
    canvas.itemconfig( f"{n0}", fill=c[0] )
    canvas.itemconfig( f"{n1}", fill=c[1] )


canvas.bind_all( '<space>', function )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tags

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def function(event=None):
    rand_num = random.randint(1,2)

    # resetting the color of existing elements
    for i in range(1, 3):
        canvas.itemconfig(f"tag{i}", font="Arial 25", fill="black")

    # highlighting the active one
    canvas.itemconfig(f"tag{rand_num}", font="Arial 25", fill="red")


canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

n1 = canvas.create_text(100, 100, font="Arial 25", text="1", tags="tag1")
n2 = canvas.create_text(100, 150, font="Arial 25", text="2", tags="tag2")

canvas.bind_all('<space>', function)

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> if it is equal to 1 then I want to change n1 and if it is equal to 2
> then I want to change n2.

- In line 9 and 10, add keyword `tags="n1`" and `tags="n2`"
- In line 16, add f-string in keyword `text=f"n{randNum}"`
- In line 18, Change `canvas.bind_all("<Key>", ..` to
  `canvas.bind_all('<space>',....`

Snippet re-wrote to add object:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()


n1 = canvas.create_text(100, 100, font="Arial 25", text="1", tags="n1")
n2 = canvas.create_text(100, 150, font="Arial 25", text="2", tags="n2")


def function(event):
    if event.keysym == 'space':
        randNum = random.randint(1,2)
        canvas.itemconfig(f"n{randNum}", font="Arial 25", fill="red", text=f"n{randNum}")

canvas.bind_all('<space>', function)


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]